# If statement with String.equals()

Tags: java, if-statement, logic

```
if ((clearance.equals("")) || (!clearance.equals("0")) || (!clearance.equals("1"))){
  System.out.println("Invalid entry, exiting.\n");
  System.exit(0);
}
```

However when I key in 0 or 1 it still prints "Invalid entry, exiting."

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: clearance is of type String. i can print the value out and it shows 0 or 1 but the if statement seems to skip it.

Comment: each instance i key in only ONE number, either 0 or 1.

Comment: Please post some lines before that. What is clearence? Whats the value of cleareance just before entering the if?

Comment: Too many parentheses. Won't break it, but makes it harder to read and reason about.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The condition should read:

```
if (!clearance.equals("0") && !clearance.equals("1")) {
```

Your current expression always evaluates to `true` (since **any** string is not equal to either "0" or "1").

Comment: Except that the first `||` may be needed (depending on how the statement is rewritten).

Comment: @aix thanks for making it clear, was puzzled by the logic, got stuck at this if loop for 45mins! thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong.

`if ((clearance.equals("")) || ((!clearance.equals("0")) && (!clearance.equals("1")))){`

Answer (score 0):

Think about it:  You're going to print the error message if `clearance != "0"` OR if `clearance != "1"`.  One or the other of those will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

if clearance is "1" then it's not "0", so you would short circuit there and the value is true. if clearance is 0, then it's not 1 so again your statement is true.